# jquery - duplicate filed and multiply

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following jquery that is simple and duplciates another field.

I would like it to also multiply that first field, example: .price = 10, .price2 = 20
(2 x .price)

I have tried usin the .val, but must be placing it incorrectly.
Here is the code I have right now.

Jquery:

```
var str = $( ".price" ).text();
$( ".price2" ).html( str );
```

Html:

```
<label class="price">10</label>
<label class="price2"></label>
```

Here is the jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/L3syd/

The above duplicates .price to .price2 in this case 10.
I would like .price2 to show .price * 2 ( or any multiplier ) to get 20

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you have never multiple the .price value

```
$( ".price2" ).html( str );
```

all you are doing is passing that value into the .price2 element.

```
$( ".price2" ).html( parseInt(str) * 2 );
```

try that...

Oooops... I just remembered I didn't pars the string.. you also need to convert your strings to be able to work with them like numeric values..

Best of luck

Comment: thanks. that fixed it. I was trying to use the .val not the parseInt